# JAVA SWING ICEPDF pdf not showing whole content

Tags: java, swing, pdf, icepdf

I am creating one small desktop application using SWING where i have one requirement to show PDF in preview panel. For achieve this requirement i am using ICEPDF library with below versions

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.icepdf.os/icepdf-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icepdf.os</groupId>
    <artifactId>icepdf-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.icepdf.os/icepdf-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icepdf.os</groupId>
    <artifactId>icepdf-viewer</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.icepdf/icepdf-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icepdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>icepdf-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.icepdf/icepdf-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icepdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>icepdf-viewer</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but it is not working properly

When i am using `org.icepdf - icepdf-core and org.icepdf - icepdf-viewer` at that time pdf showing like this
[image]

there is more text in pdf i cant share original pdf content otherwise i will show you

and when i am using `org.icepdf.os - icepdf-core and org.icepdf.os - icepdf-viewer` at that time i got below exception

```
The type org.icepdf.core.views.DocumentViewController cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

can you please how to show whole pdf content in my preview panel?

my whole source code is below

```
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    panel.setBounds(470, 0, 600, 700);
    
                    // Construct a PropertiesManager from the default properties
                    // file and default message bundle
                    PropertiesManager properties = new PropertiesManager(
                            System.getProperties(),
                            ResourceBundle
                                    .getBundle(PropertiesManager.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_BUNDLE));
    
                    // Build a SwingViewFactory configured with the controller
                    SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller,
                            properties);
    
                    // Use the factory to build a JPanel that is pre-configured
                    // with a complete, active Viewer UI.
                    viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();
                    viewerComponentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(580, 650));
                    viewerComponentPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(580, 650));
                    // add copy keyboard command
                    ComponentKeyBinding.install(controller, viewerComponentPanel);
    
                    controller.setPageViewMode(
                            DocumentViewControllerImpl.ONE_COLUMN_VIEW, false);
    
                    // add interactive mouse link annotation support via callback
                    controller.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
                            new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(
                                    controller.getDocumentViewController()));
    
                    // Create a JFrame to display the panel in
                    panel.add(viewerComponentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
                    contentPane.add(panel);

                    controller.openDocument(file);
```

Comment: *"there is more text in pdf i cant share original pdf content otherwise i will show you"* No need to share the whole document, but you could create a proper [mre], write a document in Word or something using some Lorem Ipsum text, save the document as PDF and try to display it. However this line `panel.setBounds(470, 0, 600, 700);` tells me you're using `null-layout` which is a bad choice. It may be the root of your problems.

Comment: @Frakcool actually this is not my whole source code.. this is part of code for my appication. I just posted that source code that show pdf content in panel

Comment: @Frakcool and yes some of files content showing properly but very rare file content is not showing may be like pdf have interactive form fields.

Comment: And I never asked for the whole source code, but for an [mre] (a brand new code that isolated the issue), that will allow us to copy-paste-compile-run the code and see the same issue as you. If you want specific help for your specific problem, help us to help you with the MRE requested, it should fit in about 100-150 lines of code and should take you about 30-60 mins to develop. I'm off to bed now. If you reply I'll see it tomorrow

Comment: @Frakcool I have this same issue http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/PDF-1050 but i dont know how to get that jar file

Comment: If you go to the release notes, it was fixed on version [6.2.0](http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/PDF-1056?jql=project%20%3D%20PDF%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%206.2%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC%2C%20created%20ASC). So use that version and that's it.

Comment: @Frakcool but i am not able to download that zip files http://www.icesoft.org/java/downloads/icepdf-downloads.jsf from this page.

Comment: Then I can't help you. This is a site for programming questions, not how to download software. You'll have to find a way or try another library

Comment: Or you should pick the most recent one, which should contain the fix as well